# Remembering selections without database asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, sessionstorage

I Want to remember the checkbox, jquery selectable selections between page refresh. This data should be remembered per tab. I have a jquery selectable which the user selects and I post an ajax request along with the selectable keyIDs and then I get the response back.There are some checkboxes as well as part of these selections, and page might get reloaded every few seconds. If the same user/ another user open another tab with the same link it should not remember these selections otherwise it should.

a) How to remember front end selections that user made between page
    requests in ASP.net MVC 
 b) How not to share the same selection data
    when the link is opened in another tab

Comment: you can use cookies and add checkbox values of each tab in a cookie

Comment: Are cookies the only option? I will have lot of things to remember like jquery selectable might have 100 cells and check boxes could be there as well along with the selectable selections. How about sessionsttorage? Are there any issues with using sessionstorage? Would it be different values for different tabs?

Comment: well it is either cookies or the localstorage for the client side

Comment: If it's only to remember values between single page requests, you can also consider TempData, otherwise it's cookies, session data or localstorage.

Answer (score 0):

Using ASP.net Session on the server

Example

```
Session["FirstName"] = FirstNameTextBox.Text;
Session["LastName"] = LastNameTextBox.Text;
```

Check out this link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

Comment: Does using asp.net session put the application on a single thread mode? One of the things either the sessionstorage(html5) or session is causing the app to single thread mode. Can anyone comment on this please?

Comment: No it does not. Session is used in the request pipeline based on an Id assigned to the session.